# How to return a List in c#

Tags: c#, collections

Below I have a method I am trying to create. The overall objective of the method is to create a list, open a database in SQL, and convert that information to a string. The problem though I am having is returning all the data. I understand for a method to work you need a return statement of some sort, however when I try to return the list, it keeps telling me

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Namespace).MyHome' to '(namespace).MyHome

So my question to you all is, can I return the list, or will I have to create another variable to return, or am I trying to return the wrong thing entirely?

Below is the method I am working on. For explanation, this method is using a class I created that holds the credentials for the data I am trying to get.

```
 private static MyHome GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
    {
        List<MyHome> myHomeInformation = new List<MyHome>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyHomeConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT USER_NAME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TRAVELER_UID FROM DATA_BASE";
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlError.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MyHome userInformation = new MyHome();
                foreach (MyHome item in myHomeInformation)
                {
                    userInformation.myHomeUserName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["USER_NAME"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeEmail = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["EMAIL"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeFirstName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["FIRST_NAME"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeLastName = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["LAST_NAME"]);
                    userInformation.myHomeTravelerUID = Utilities.FromDBValue<string>(reader["TRAVELER_UID"]);
                    myHomeInformation.Add(userInformation);
                }
            }
        }
        return myHomeInformation;
    }
```

Here is the class that holds the credentials:

```
class MyHome : IEnumerable<MyHome>
{
    public string myHomeUserName { get; set; }
    public string myHomeEmail { get; set; }
    public string myHomeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string myHomeLastName { get; set; }
    public string myHomeTravelerUID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also create `userInformation` object inside loop. Otherwise it will be same object with multiple copies.

Comment: Why does `MyHome` inherit from `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @RonBeyer in research I found IEnumerable to help so I tried it and it didn't work. I just forgot to remove it I believe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
private static MyHome GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
```

with

```
private static List<MyHome> GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
```

the return type should be a list of objects and not just a object

Comment: Perfect. After looking at yours and going back to mine it makes sense that it has to be a list and not just an object.

Answer (score 1):

A `List<MyHome>` is not a `MyHome`. If you want your function to return a `List<MyHome>`, declare it as such.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the return type of the function to be a List of MyHome.

```
private static List<MyHome> GetUserDataFromMyHome(string username)
```

Otherwise whatever is calling this is expecting to get one instance of MyHome.